# Use case to set a parameter in my where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a file that intakes yearly totals for tax due and breaks it down by month like : fcurJanuaryTotal, fcurFebruaryTotal, fcurMarchTotal etc. When someone receives a notice to pay taxes on a given month I receive a 'lead' which sets the pay period in this format dd-mm-yyyy (in a column named 'fdtmFilingPeriod'). I have a program that uses a query to create the lead and then create an estimated payment for their taxes and pulls the financials from the file I receive with the monthly totals. It is desired that no estimated payments be created that are less than $100.

```
SELECT  CONCAT  ('SUTRTN',
        '_',
        MONTH(p.fdtmFilingPeriod),
        '_',
        YEAR(p.fdtmFilingPeriod),
        '_',
        a.flngAccountKey) AS fstrRecordKey,
    i.fstrIdType,
    i.fstrId,
    a.flngCustomerKey,
    a.flngAccountKey,
    p.fdtmFilingPeriod,
    0.00 AS fcurAmount 

FROM    tblAccount a,
    tblID i,
    tblPeriod p,
    tblReturnExpectation re 

WHERE   a.flngVer           =  0 
AND a.fstrAccountType   =  'SUT' 
AND a.flngCustomerKey   =  i.flngCustomerKey 
AND a.flngAccountKey    =  i.flngAccountKey 
AND i.flngVer           =  0 
AND i.fstrIdType        =  'ACC' 
AND a.flngAccountKey    =  p.flngAccountKey 
AND p.flngVer           =  0 
AND p.fdtmFilingPeriod  >= @pdtmFilingPeriodFrom 
AND p.fdtmFilingPeriod  <= @pdtmFilingPeriodTo 
AND a.flngAccountKey    =  re.flngAccountKey 
AND p.fdtmFilingPeriod  =  re.fdtmFilingPeriod 
AND re.flngVer          =  0 
AND re.fstrStatus       =  'GNR' 
AND re.fdtmDue          <= DATEADD(dd, -45, @pdtmRunDate) 
AND EXISTS  (SELECT 1 

    FROM    tblSalesTaxReturnAmouts stra 

    WHERE   a.flngCustomerKey  = stra.flngCustomerKey 
    AND a.flngAccountKey   = stra.flngAccountKey 
    AND YEAR(re.fdtmFilingPeriod) = YEAR(stra.fdtmFilingPeriod)
    AND CASE
            When MONTH(stra.fdtmFilingPeriod) = 1 THEN fcurJanuaryTotalDue > 100
            When Month(stra.fdtmFilingPeriod) = 2 THEN fcurFebruaryTotalDUe > 100
            WHEN MONTH(re.fdtmFilingPeriod) = 3 THEN fcurMarchTotalDue > 100
            WHEN MONTH(re.fdtmFilingPeriod) = 4 THEN fcurAprilTotalDue > 100
            WHEN MONTH(re.fdtmFilingPeriod) = 5 THEN fcurMayTotalDue > 100
            WHEN MONTH(re.fdtmFilingPeriod) = 6 THEN fcurJuneTotalDue > 100
            WHEN MONTH(re.fdtmFilingPeriod) = 7 THEN fcurJulyTotalDue > 100
            WHEN MONTH(re.fdtmFilingPeriod) = 8 THEN fcurAugustTotalDue > 100
            WHEN MONTH(re.fdtmFilingPeriod) = 9 THEN fcurSeptemberTotalDue > 100
            WHEN MONTH(re.fdtmFilingPeriod) = 10 THEN fcurOctoberTotalDue > 100
            WHEN MONTH(re.fdtmFilingPeriod) = 11 THEN fcurNovemberTotalDue > 100
            WHEN MONTH(re.fdtmFilingPeriod) = 12 THEN fcurDecemberTotalDue > 100
        END
```

I get a few syntax errors after the first line:

> 'Expecting '(' or Select statement before re.fdtmFilingPeriod

and then one saying the

> '>' on the first line has 'incorrect syntax.

I thought to do it this way because I can get a lead for any of the 12 months. But I am wondering if this is even possible or if there is a better way.

Comment: I suggest creating a [mre] with sample data and desired results, and with emphasis on **minimal** we don't want to see your complex production code (it will put many people off), we need the simplest example which demonstrates the problem you are facing. And potentially while you cut it down into a simpler example you'll find the issue yourself.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: But part of your issue is you misunderstand how to use a `case` *expression*. Its not a statement as the documentation clearly shows. It can only return a scalar value, not execute an expression. With that in mind you can probably solve your issues.

Comment: I think the real root of the problem is that the data is denormalized. You should have these as rows not columns. Also don't use comma-joins, they are very out of style, difficult to read and easy to make a mistake.

Comment: @DaleK Admittedly in most languages and DBMSs `BOOLEAN` is also an expression (and is so internally in SQL Server), so it does make sense. This not the typical `CASE` flow control issue, it's just the use of a `BOOLEAN` where it's not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The `CASE` expression cannot be used to choose a relational expression, but it *can* be used to choose a value that is then used in a relational expression. There is also a form where you specify the *selector* once and only specify the *matching case values* in the `WHEN`. See [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) for syntax documentation.

Try:

```
    AND CASE MONTH(stra.fdtmFilingPeriod)
            WHEN 1 THEN fcurJanuaryTotalDue
            WHEN 2 THEN fcurFebruaryTotalDue
            WHEN 3 THEN fcurMarchTotalDue
            WHEN 4 THEN fcurAprilTotalDue
            WHEN 5 THEN fcurMayTotalDue
            WHEN 6 THEN fcurJuneTotalDue
            WHEN 7 THEN fcurJulyTotalDue
            WHEN 8 THEN fcurAugustTotalDue
            WHEN 9 THEN fcurSeptemberTotalDue
            WHEN 10 THEN fcurOctoberTotalDue
            WHEN 11 THEN fcurNovemberTotalDue
            WHEN 12 THEN fcurDecemberTotalDue
        END > 100
```

The `CHOOSE()` function might also be used for this particular case, since the selector is an integer between 1 and N, suitable for use as an index parameter.

```
    AND CHOOSE(
            MONTH(stra.fdtmFilingPeriod),
            fcurJanuaryTotalDue, fcurFebruaryTotalDue, fcurMarchTotalDue,
            fcurAprilTotalDue,   fcurMayTotalDue,      fcurJuneTotalDue,
            fcurJulyTotalDue,    fcurAugustTotalDue,   fcurSeptemberTotalDue,
            fcurOctoberTotalDue, fcurNovemberTotalDue, fcurDecemberTotalDue
        ) > 100
```

Comment: Never seen `choose` before... thats cool

Comment: Can't recall if I have ever used it or even seen it used before.. It was something I noticed and I made a mental note of a while back when scanning the documentation.

Comment: You can't know everything, but it is good to try to know what you don't know so when you know you don't know something, you at least know where to find what you don't know.

Comment: Thanks. This is great info and the first recommendation is seeming to be a working option. I am very new to sql and can do somethings but still have plenty to learn. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how to implement case in a where condition. you need to compare what was chosen in case with a value.

```
declare @t table (id int identity(1,1) not null
,ColName varchar(50)
,fcurJanuaryTotalDue    int
,fcurFebruaryTotalDUe   int
,fcurMarchTotalDue      int
,fcurAprilTotalDue      int
,fcurMayTotalDue        int
,fcurJuneTotalDue       int
,fcurJulyTotalDue       int
,fcurAugustTotalDue     int
,fcurSeptemberTotalDue  int
,fcurOctoberTotalDue    int
,fcurNovemberTotalDue   int
,fcurDecemberTotalDue   int
)

insert into @t values 
 ('name1', 1000,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
,('name2', 1,2000,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
,('name3', 1,2,30000,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
,('name4', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
,('name5', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
,('name6', 1,2,3,4,5,600000,7,8,9,10,11,12)
,('name7', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7000,8,9,10,11,12)
,('name8', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8000,9,10,11,12)
,('name9', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
,('name10', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1000,11,12)
,('name11', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1100,12)
,('name12', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,90,10,11,120000)

select * from @t
where
    CASE
        When id = 1 THEN fcurJanuaryTotalDue 
        When id = 2 THEN fcurFebruaryTotalDUe   
        WHEN id = 3 THEN fcurMarchTotalDue      
        WHEN id = 4 THEN fcurAprilTotalDue      
        WHEN id = 5 THEN fcurMayTotalDue        
        WHEN id = 6 THEN fcurJuneTotalDue       
        WHEN id = 7 THEN fcurJulyTotalDue       
        WHEN id = 8 THEN fcurAugustTotalDue     
        WHEN id = 9 THEN fcurSeptemberTotalDue  
        WHEN id = 10 THEN fcurOctoberTotalDue   
        WHEN id = 11 THEN fcurNovemberTotalDue  
        WHEN id = 12 THEN fcurDecemberTotalDue  
     END < 100
```

the result would be id 4,5,and 9

| id | ColName | fcurJanuaryTotalDue | fcurFebruaryTotalDUe | fcurMarchTotalDue | fcurAprilTotalDue | fcurMayTotalDue | fcurJuneTotalDue | fcurJulyTotalDue | fcurAugustTotalDue | fcurSeptemberTotalDue | fcurOctoberTotalDue | fcurNovemberTotalDue | fcurDecemberTotalDue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | name4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 5 | name5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 9 | name9 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |